# Is there any way to open remss gmi files in R?

Tags: r, binary-data

Sea surface temperature data from REMSS (https://www.remss.com/measurements/sea-surface-temperature/) in binary format and unable to read with R. I tried with readBin function but was unable to read data.

```
testdata <- "G:/forecast/gmi/f35_20210923v8.2_d3d"
readBin(testdata,numeric(), size = 1440*720*6)
```

REMSS has provided scripts for Matlab, Python, CPP and Fortran but not for R. Is there any way to open the [attached file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WHACp4pNybgWUOnxNlFS_VVlf0A85VJY/view?usp=sharing) in R? [Scripts for Matlab, Python, CPP and Fortran with example files](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KS9o20YjCGLQrQI8talJlTfrTK0UFFDB/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Did you have the change to take a look at [this function](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/oce/html/read.amsr.html)? Maybe it can help you. Other option is to use `reticulate` package and then use the provided `Python` code to read it. If you have the python code (I couldn't find it) I can help you out.

Comment: @patL I tried read.amsr() as follows. read.amsr("G:/forecast/gmi/f35_20210923v8.2_d3d", debug = getOption("oceDebug"))
Error in read.amsr("G:/forecast/gmi/f35_20210923v8.2_d3d", debug = getOption("oceDebug")) : 
  Cannot (yet) read 6-chunk data. Please contact the developers if you need this file (and be sure to send the file to them). Python scripts are available in the above link. I tried to run it with Python 3.9 but the scripts were written with python2 and gives errors. I'm very much appreciate if you can guide me to solve this.